# VSTS CI NuGet push to private feed success but doesn't show anything

Tags: azure-artifacts

I have a solution building as part of continuous integration, with a step to push a class library out to my VSTS package feed. This worked the first time the CI build ran and created the package. The second time it shows it was successful, but a new version doesn't exist or any sign of a new package.

Prior to the second build, I promoted the package to @release, if that makes a difference?

Output of the CI build for NuGet push is below:

`2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet push
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z Task         : NuGet
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z Version      : 2.0.5
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
2017-07-24T10:48:51.4888942Z ==============================================================================
2017-07-24T10:48:51.9019022Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2017-07-24T10:48:51.9059034Z Active code page: 65001
2017-07-24T10:48:51.9219032Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2017-07-24T10:48:51.9409032Z Detected NuGet version 4.0.0.2283 / 4.0.0
2017-07-24T10:48:52.1389068Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
2017-07-24T10:48:52.1449080Z ##[warning]No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_150.config
2017-07-24T10:48:52.1549071Z [command]d:\a\_tasks\NuGetCommand_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\2.0.5\VstsNuGetPush\0.13.0\VstsNuGetPush.exe d:\a\1\a\WAGR2.DAL.1.0.0-CI-20170724-104834.nupkg -Source https://forgan.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/1b92b113-5d65-4b30-8749-9362924199b5/nuget/v3/index.json -AccessToken ******** -NonInteractive -Verbosity Detailed
2017-07-24T10:48:52.7149186Z Trying to authenticate with auth token.
2017-07-24T10:48:53.3099300Z Successfully authenticated.
2017-07-24T10:48:53.3189305Z Authentication and request took 00:00:01.0127956
2017-07-24T10:48:53.3589311Z Adding package WAGR2.DAL.1.0.0-CI-20170724-104834.nupkg to feed 1b92b113-5d65-4b30-8749-9362924199b5 on https://forgan.pkgs.visualstudio.com/.
2017-07-24T10:48:53.3589311Z Trying to add package to feed without uploading.
2017-07-24T10:48:53.3589311Z Adding package to feed.
2017-07-24T10:48:54.1399458Z The package content is not already on the service.
2017-07-24T10:48:54.1399458Z Uploading package content.
2017-07-24T10:48:56.0287785Z Done uploading package content.
2017-07-24T10:48:56.0287785Z Adding package to feed.
2017-07-24T10:48:57.3686297Z Successfully added package to feed.
2017-07-24T10:48:57.4256306Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet push`

**UPDATE**

The Nuget Pack option was to use automatic package versioning based on `date & time`.

The package doesn't appear in the NuGet gallery along side the others, which is also odd.

Comment: Thank you for including the build output. I've checked the service logs, and all signs point towards your new package version getting pushed to the feed successfully.
Are you using the VSTS UI or something like the Visual Studio nuget package manager to look for the new version? Just to sanity check, regardless of the tool, have you refreshed it, and are you sure that you're not looking at versions in the release view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this was happening, but what now works is:

- Remove package from feed
- Change the Nuget Pack Automatic package versioning from `date & time` to `build number`, using the Build Number Format (under Options): `'$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)'`
- On NuGet Push, I also had to check the box `Allow duplicates to be skipped`

Packages now publish every time and also appear in the NuGet gallery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have publish the package `WAGR2.DAL.1.0.0-CI-20170724-104834.nupkg` successful to your VSTS feed. So please find the package with below steps：

1. In you VSTS feed, set Release view to All.

   [image]
2. Find the package `WAGR2.DAL` and click it.
3. If you have the package version as `WAGR2.DAL.1.0.0`, it will be treated as the latest version. And you can find the version `1.0.0-CI-20170724-104834` in drop down list.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I did all of this and it is not there. The modified date still shows 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you show the screen shot for your detail build definition settings (especially for **nuget pack** and **nuget push** tasks)?